# how to access data in habtm relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

try to implement has_and_belongs_to_many relationship one documents has many group
one group has many documents

a join table call documents_group created

Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
end
```

Model 2

```
class Documents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  before_post_process :resize_images

  def image?
    avatar_content_type =~ %r{^(image|(x-)?application)/(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|pjpeg|png|x-png)$}
  end

private

  def resize_images
    return false unless image?
  end
end
```

controller create 
    def create
    @document = Documents.all

```
 @document = Documents.create( params[:document] )

 @document.user_id = current_user.id
 @document.save
 redirect_to root_path
 end
```

migration is

```
     def self.up
     create_table :documents_groups ,:id => false do |t|
      t.integer :documents_id
      t.integer :group_id
     end

    end
```

now i want to acess all documents coreespond to a group how to do

Answer (score 2):

To access all the documents of a group, just call `#documents` on the specific group model. For example:

```
Group.find(params[:id]).documents #=> Collection of groups documents as Array
```

You might run into a problem though because it looks like you're never assigning the new document to a group. You can do that several ways, one possible way is adding the following before `@document.save` in `DocumentsController#create` (assuming you have a parameter named `group_id`)

```
@document.group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
```

Comment: can u tell me how to access documents which has no group

Comment: `Document.all` will give you all your documents. To find a specific model, you can use `Document.find_by_[column]` where `[column]` is the name of a Document attribute such as `id`.

Comment: Or are you trying to access only the Documents that have no group?

Comment: yes i m trying to access only the documents that have no group?

Comment: `Document.where("group_id is null")` will return documents with no group.

Comment: If this answered your question, it'd be nice if you accepted the answer.